# How can I move every other letter of a string

Tags: python, shift

I would like help with one cipher, specifically such that I have words/letters and each shift by a certain number

example word Example

+1 input number
output is

```
example
```

+2 input numbers
output is

```
Eapexml
```

I have this script but it only works for two shifit

```
def encrypt(message,shift):
   return "%s%s" % (message[::shift],message[1::shift])


print(encrypt("123456",2))

135246
```

and I really need other combinations

(preferably according to how they are written in the object)

`number [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` this is just an example, I will also use other numbers like prime etc...

but I don't know how to write the script, could someone help me?

Comment: Where has gone the last 'e' in the +3 exemple?

Comment: What rule governs conversion to uppercase? Also, show an example that doesn't have repeated letters. That will make your algorithm clearer

Comment: I  think you must bring us more information about the algorithm you want to code. Your examples are not enough.

Comment: @zigma12 he just needs to change it by a certain number and I'll do the rest

Comment: @Nobikk EMEMxlAp has repeated characters. You need to show both input and output for the various values of *shift*. Who is "he"?

Comment: @Stuart it always continues at the end with the remaining characters

Comment: @Stuart input `123456` output is 2 shift `135246`

Comment: @Nobikk I voted to close this due to lack of clarity. If you need help you have to provide a minimal reproducible example. You don't seem to be inclined to do that

Comment: however, I provided an example in numbers, it should work for letters anyway

`print(encrypt("123456",2))`
`135246`

chooses every other letter/number and then continues from the end again where it left off

Comment: @Nobikk But you still haven't explained what the output should be if *shift* is, for example, 3. And you haven't explained the capitalisation

Comment: @Stuart it doesn't matter about uppercase and lowercase letters, he can move anything in the text, he doesn't know the characters

Comment: @Stuart For me, the script works correctly for +2 shift, but the rest doesn't and that's the problem that I don't know how to do it

Comment: Last chance if you want help: What are expected outputs for `"ABCDEFGH"` and shift in 1, 2, 3, 4? Give us those 4 outputs.

Comment: @Nobikk Why ADGBEHCC when there is only one C in the input?

Comment: @Stuart it's a mistake, don't take it all away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
def encrypt(message, shift):
    return ''.join(message[i::shift] for i in range(shift)) if shift > 1 else message

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(encrypt('ABCDEFGH', i))
```

**Output:**

```
ABCDEFGH
ACEGBDFH
ADGBEHCF
AEBFCGDH
```

**Observation:**

This is an awful encryption algorithm if only because the first letter never changes

Comment: Upvoted but I noticed a difference in logic so I'm clearly unaware of what OP really wanted here. I thought he wanted to shift every nth character to the back of the string in order. What is the logic of `ADGBEHCF` as an outcome? Since that's where both our solutions start to differ.

Comment: @JvdV The question does contain anomalies but this is my interpretation which the OP has accepted so I can only assume that it's correct

Comment: would it be possible to modify it so that there are more shifts, not just how many letters are there? i.e. shift 10, for example, every 10 letters

Comment: @Nobikk That's what the second parameter passed to *encrypt()* does

Comment: yes if have more + no working onli first range(leght)

Comment: @Nobikk I have no idea what that means. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to see if this is possible with a regular expression for fun:

```
import regex as re

def encrypt(message,shift):
    rgx = re.compile(fr'(?:.{{{shift-1}}}|.\G)\K.')
    return re.sub(rgx, '', message) + ''.join(re.findall(rgx, message))

for i in range(1, 5):
    print(encrypt('example', i))
```

Prints:

```
example
eapexml
exmpeal
exaplem
```

Comment: **Note**: I read the question as such; Get every nth character and move it to the back of the string in that specific order. This differs from the accepted answer and therefor could well be wrong on my end.

Comment: would it be possible to modify it so that there are more shifts, not just how many letters are there? i.e. shift 10, for example, every 10 letters

Comment: @nobikk, new questions get new posts with examples and expected output. To be honest, this question is too vague and I still don't know if my answer actually answered your intention. Also, you are welcome....